# Emails are automatically sent to Chinese addresses - scam/spam/virus?

Tags: email, security, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention, internet-security

My IT-colleagues have noticed that a (non-IT) user in our work network has some strange things going on in her mailbox.

In the user's sent folder we noticed a bunch of emails with all Chinese characters and they wre sent to Chinese email addresses. She did not send them, and there are 30-40-50 emails sent, all within a minute.
Some of those emails are not delivered, but a lot are.

We have already changed her password, but this is still happening.
We have ESET Endpoint Security, and we did run a check on the computer, but it did not find anything.

It is just the one user, and it looks like something on her computer sends out 30-50 emails at the same time, periodically (not at regular intervals, but something like once-twice a week or bi-weekly).

The recipients' email addresses are mostly rangom strings of characters with providers like 126.com, or yahoo.cn, and such.

Does anyone either know what this could be, or have anny suggestions as to what to try next, or how to investigate this?

EDIT (after davidgo's reply): Thank you for the reply, this does not sound good.

Mainly because we have just provided her with a new computer a couple of weeks ago, and this is something that she says "has been going on for a while, i just have been deleting these every day". She also has her email account synced with her smartphone, so we are suspecting that maybe it was something she did on her phone.

We put a couple of the email subjects into Google Translate and they do look like your average spam with ads.

The bigger problem is that the machine and the email account even more so are important players here... crucial correspondence with "official parties" is done on it, so it is 99.99% out of the question to isolate the machine let alone changing the email address, or anything of the sort - unless i can show definite proof that there was a breach and/or data theft has occured.

---

2 months+ after my initial post - after changing some passwords and such - the number of these emails has declined, but the issue seems to persist, at least for 2 users (as opposed to 5 earlier).

Spamrl says:

> **The sending IP (xxxxxx) is listed as a source of dictionary attacks.**
>
> This means we have been seeing significant traffic to non-existing mailboxes originating from your IP(s), compared to legitimate deliveries. This is automated, and NOT caused by spam reports.

I snapped a screencap of what i see in the EAC.
This is for 1 user, the bottom 7 emails were "sent" within a minute, the top 2 a couple of hours later. ("Olvasatlan" in the subject just means "unread" in my native language.)

[image]

I am also not sure what is meant by my domain being the SOURCE of dictionary attacks.
The addresses in the TO field do seem like non-existing mailboxes, like the spamrl message suggests, but i don't know where to go from here with my investigation.

Worth noting also is that sometimes some of these show "Read" in the subject.

**Any help, tips, suggestions would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing appears to have the hallmarks of a compromised computer which is part of a spamming botnet - despite ESET not picking up on it.

It appears from what you say that the targetted group are Chinese.  You may be able to bolster this theory by getting some of the emails translated.

There is no simple way to solve this problem (other then possibly wiping her system and reinstalling it).  You might want to try temporarily disabling ESET and using some other AV scanners.  Also, you should try Malwarebytes, as in my experience this finds "not-strictly-speaking viri" which are, to all intents and purposes malware, and which other software misses.  In this vain, look for software installed which she does not strictly speaking need - things like games, toolbars etc.

Unfortunately anything else becomes very hard. You could try and isolate the system so its not used for anything important, dump all traffic flows to/from it, then pick through all traffic sent to and from it to see if you can find the command server.  It might not be worth the effort.